# Regular expression not working in dotnet C# but works in online editors

Tags: c#, .net, regex

String : SHT. 141

```
Regex sheetNumber = new Regex("(?<=SHT[.][ ]?)[0-9]{0,9}");

string cellText = _selectedTable.Cells.Select(x => x.Value).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);

var match = sheetNumber.Match(cellText);

    
if (match.Success)
{
    var value = match.Value;
}
```

I am trying to extract 141 from it. The regex is matched successfully but the value is null in dotnet C#. **But when I try it in online editors I am able to get 141 out of it**. I can't figure out what is happening?

Comment: How do you obtain the `match`?

Comment: Ok, you need `(?<=SHT[.][ ]?)[0-9]{1,9}`, i.e. you need to match at least one digit with `{1,9}`. Your regex matches an empty string right after `SHT.` and since you only extract the first match with `Regex.Match`, you just get it, an empty string. If you used `Regex.Matches`, your expected match would be the second match.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I learnt regex yesterday and was so frustrated by this. Again, thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe `Regex.Match(cellText, @"(?<=SHT\.\s*)\d+")` will be better.